# Getting layers created in custom toolbox python script to add to mxd?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, layers, search

I'm trying to create a simple search tool so that my colleagues can easily query a database. My first version is like this.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
SearchTerm = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Fuzzy = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

if Fuzzy == False:
     NewLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"W:\Source.lyr","Search Results (" + SearchTerm + ")","PROC_NAME LIKE '%" + SearchTerm + "%'")
else:
    NewLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"W:\Source.lyr","Search Results (" + SearchTerm + ")","PROC_NAME = '" + SearchTerm + "'")
```

This works as expected if I just run the code through the python window (with the parameters hardcoded) but if I run it as a script in toolbox nothing happens. I suppose ArcMap doesnt automatically add the layer you create in a script, so I've added:

```
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,NewLayer,"TOP")
```

This doesn't give add a layer to my mxd and gives me the error message: `Runtime error <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>:`

Surely this should be pretty simple. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation is always confusing. There are two types of 'Layers' in arcpy. The feature layer, which you are creating, isn't the type you can add to a map. The other is the layer generated from the mapping module. This is the one you want. Instead of `MakeFeatureLayer`, try this:

```
    NewLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"W:\Source.lyr")
```

Then you can perform your `arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,NewLayer,"TOP")`.